# Scroll event not being triggered over SVG object in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, svg, mozilla

I've noticed the scroll event (not sure about others) is not being propagated when scrolling over an `object` element like this:

```
<object id="svg_object" data="https://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/kiwi.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

[Reproduction of the issue in Firefox](https://jsfiddle.net/suaguLzp/9/)

Scroll over the red background and you'll see how a message get displayed in the java-script console as a result.
Scrolling over the SVG (or yellow background) won't do anything.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
addMouse();

function MouseWheelHandler() {
    console.log("Getting the event");
}

function addMouse() {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('mousewheel', MouseWheelHandler, false); //IE9, Chrome, Safari, Oper
        document.addEventListener('wheel', MouseWheelHandler, false); //Firefox
        document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', MouseWheelHandler, false); //Old Firefox
    } else {
        document.attachEvent('onmousewheel', MouseWheelHandler); //IE 6/7/8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the SVG content pointer-events: none i.e.

```
#svg_object {

    background:yellow;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

otherwise the SVG document gets all the pointer events rather than the html container.